# Eclipse Juno bad performance slow hangs freezes in Java Editor

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having very bad performance problems with Eclipse Juno 4.2.

I can consistently reproduce the issue with in my workspace.  The problem is only with *.java files.  Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. I open a workspace with java files
2. wait for "Initializing Java Tooling" to finish
3. open a java file in the Java Editor
4. type some garbarage... let eclipse underline it with red.
5. put my mouse over the red word
6. Hang/Freeze for 10 seconds.

I have tried many things.  I tried a few changes to eclipse.ini.  Didn't help.  I just tried turning off **Report problems as you type**.  Now the issue has changed.  Eclipse will no longer underline errors in red.  Now when I save a java file it takes 10 seconds.

I tried renaming my `workspace.xmi`.  (That seems to reset workspace back to "factory" settings)  That did not help.

I can use Eclipse Juno to open other workspaces that do not have java files and there is no performance issue.

- Help > About Eclipse SDK shows Version: **4.2.2** Build id: M20130204-1200.
- Red Hat Ent. Linux 6.4
- java version "1.6.0"
- I'm running `eclipse &` from terminal.
- eclipse is firing off with `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: It's juno bugs. Use kepler instead of juno.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought someone might say that.  I think all of the Juno performance issues were fixed in 2 service packs 1 and 2.  My version of Juno (4.2.2) has both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a generic troubleshooting method for eclipse on linux/mac OS, then strace is for you.  I'm 2 for 2 with it.

I used strace a long time ago to troubleshoot an eclipse issue and I'm glad I **[documented it on my blog](http://jessemon.blogspot.com/search?q=strace)** because it's really not trivial.  Eclipse uses so many threads.

Anyway, I found one strace log where it was trying to access a very strange file in a network directory that is the directory of one of my coworkers!  I found that the `.classpath` was checked into git with his network paths.  I suppose eclipse was trying to access those paths and was timing out.  Here's an example of the `.classpath`:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/net/dir/myfriend/.m2/repository/blah/blah.jar">
    <attributes>
    ...
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

I removed these paths from the .classpath files.  (Regenerated some using maven and removed the `sourcepath` attribute for some others.)

Now eclipse is running FAST!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

add this line to eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```